# Vimeo Integration using DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: oauth, dotnetopenauth, vimeo

I am trying to use Vimeo services on a web application where users need to be able to upload and list/watch videos. I have created a Vimeo App and they have given an `Access token` and an `Access token secret` using which I can access my own account.

Could someone tell me how do I do that from .NET C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiate an `OAuthConsumer` from DotNetOpenAuth, passing in an `InMemoryTokenManager` which you can find from the samples. Add your access token and secret to that token manager. You will also need your consumer key and secret. Then use the `OAuthConsumer` instance to make authorized outbound calls.

Hint: You won't need to do any of the OAuth authorization flows, since you already have the access token.